# Python/Pandas - Scraping Webpage Search Results Across Multiple Pages

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with a friend to try and pull in the results of several webpages into a dataframe (https://motos.coches.net/ocasion/barcelona/?pg=1&fi=oTitle&or=1&Tops=1, where page number would increase). I haven't worked much with web scraping before and have attempted using Pandas read_html and BeautifulSoup, but am having trouble finding where to start.

Ideally, we'd like to pull all 5000+ results into a CSV showing title, date posted, kilometers, year, CC, and location.

Is something like this easily doable with Pandas and a web scraping library? Thanks for your help!

Comment: First step is about downloading the web resource. You can use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library for that. Here is a [tuto using Requests, Beautifulsoup, and Panda](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/web-scraping-with-pandas-and-beautifulsoup/)

Comment: I did see this tutorial during my initial search. I tried modifying the examples for my usage, but BeautifulSoup gave an `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown an effort to reach a solution yourself, however you can do something like this:

```
offset = 0
pg = 1
base_url = 'https://url?start={0}&pg={1}'

url = base_url.format(offset,pg)
results = first page from BeautifulSoup scrape or requests.get
all_results= results

while results:
    # Rebuild url base on current start.
    start += rows
    url = base_url.format(offset, pg)
    results = next page from BeautifulSoup scrape or requests.get
    all_results += results
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, albeit probably not the most elegant:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

base_url = 'https://motos.coches.net/ocasion/barcelona/?pg={}&fi=CreationDate&or=-1'

#excluding page from base_url for further adding
res = []

for page in range(1,300): # unknown last page

    request = requests.get(base_url.format(page), headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}) # here adding page    
    if request.status_code == 404: #added just in case of error
        break
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'lxml')

    for url in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col2-grid'):
        res.append([
            url.find('h2', class_ = 'floatleft').contents[0].encode('utf8')
            ,url.find('p', class_ = 'data floatright').contents[0].encode('utf8')
            ,url.find('p', class_ = 'preu').contents[0].encode('utf8')
            ,url.find('span', class_ = 'd1').contents[0].encode('utf8')
            ,url.find('span', class_ = 'd2').contents[0].encode('utf8')
            ,url.find('span', class_ = 'd3').contents[0].encode('utf8')
            ,url.find('span', class_ = 'lloc').contents[0].encode('utf8')
                    ]
                  )
    sleep(2) #pause code

    #create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['title', 'date_posted', 'price_in_euros', 'km', 'year', 'engine_size', 'location'])
    df = df.replace({'<span>|</span>': ''}, regex=True) #remove span tags

    df['engine_size_metric'] = None
    df.loc[df['engine_size'].str.contains(' cc'),'engine_size_metric'] = 'cc'
    df.loc[df['engine_size'].str.contains(' kw'),'engine_size_metric'] = 'kw'

    df['price_in_euros'] = df['price_in_euros'].replace({'\.|€': ''}, regex=True)
    df['price_in_euros'] = df['price_in_euros'].astype(float)

    df['km'] = df['km'].replace({'\.| km': ''}, regex=True)
    df['km'] = df['km'].replace({'N/D': None}, regex=True)
    df['km'] = df['km'].astype(float)

    df['engine_size'] = df['engine_size'].str.split(' ').str[0].replace({'\.|cc|kw': ''}, regex=True)
    df.loc[df['engine_size']=='','engine_size'] = None
    df['engine_size'] = df['engine_size'].astype(float)

    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```